# returning NaN and Undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

```
var currDice, totDice, dice, complete;

function moveIt(){
  dice = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1,
  currDice = 40,
  totDice = totDice+complete,
  complete = dice * currDice
  return totDice;
};
```

The function `moveIt` returns `NaN`.

It should return multiple of 40 till six randomly and keep the previous value.

If I remove it returns `Undefined`.

I know it is a scope problem. Please help.

Comment: Where did you initialise `complete`? What do the bottom three lines have to do with your problem? You should declare your variables with `var`, `let` or `const`.

Comment: You should provide more clarity regarding the code and what are you trying to do. From where are you calling `moveIt` function ?

Comment: *This function `moveit` returns `NaN`* No, it returns nothing, because it doesn't even parse, because of the misplaced `var` keyword.

Comment: @trincot its now returning only nan as i declared globally

Comment: @torazaburo just edited plz have a look

Comment: @AnuragSinghBisht have a look edited

Comment: I think your questions should be named "how to debug scripts" (someone removed the end of the question where the author asked help for debugging...)

Comment: What does this mean? *If I remove it returns Undefined.*

Comment: I repeat: *Where did you **initialise** `complete`?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `complete` before initialising it! you habe to swap your lines of code:

```
function moveIt(beforeTotal) {
    var dice = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    var currDice = 40;
    var complete = dice * currDice;
    var totDice = (beforeTotal || 0)+complete;
    return totDice;
};

var total = moveIt();
console.log(total);
total = moveIt(total);
console.log(total);
```

I try to point out how this method work.

You can call this function without an inital value. Then `(beforeTotal || 0)` is `(undefined || 0)` and will evaluate to `0`, that's JS logic, and you get the result for one dice.

If you pass a value to this function it will be used to add `complete` to it. By passing 1000 and complete gets 120, you get 1120 out of it.

All other variables are only available in this function.

Comment: totDice is initially undefined too, so it will still cast itself to NaN

Comment: Basically you pass the initial value for the incrementation, keep a reference of it and then pass the incremented value etc..
I'll suppose @Caesar2011 should explain it since it's his answer.

Comment: thanks so much for the help... well so u say this argumrnt beforetotal holds the previous value? plz sory to disturb but explain plz and thank u.

Comment: TL;DR: Yes, it's an inital value. You can call this function without an inital value. Then (beforeTotal || 0) is (undefined || 0) and will evaluate to 0, that's JS logic, and you get the result for one dice. If you pass a value to this function it will be used to add `complete` to it. By passing 1000 and complete gets 120, you get 1120 out of it. I hope its clear.

Comment: @Caesar2011  thanks for the help " By passing 1000 and complete gets 120" got it by this example, but cud we pass the previous dice value suppose it was (3*40)120 and now (1) ie 40 and hence 120+40 = 160... becoz its comin backwards

Comment: Yes, that's what I did with my example below with `console.log`. Open your console by pressing F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I and view the result.

Comment: now i know it! thanks for the help and sorry for the headache... :) @Caesar2011

Answer (score 0):

Initialy `totDIce` is undefined and when you add undefined to something, you get the value casted to `NaN`

```
function moveIt(){

    //memoizing the mutable value as key of the function itself
     moveIt.totDice = moveIt.totDice || 0;   

     // you might wanna wrap it with parseInt()/Math.floor()/Math.ceil()
     var dice = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
     var currDice = 40;
     var complete = dice * currDice;
     var totDice = totDice+complete;
     return moveIt.totDice ;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`var totDice;` will have `undefined` and that's why you get `NaN`

Assign `totDice = 0` on the first line...

Also move `complete = dice * currDice` line above because `complete` has no value yet

```
  var currDice, totDice = 0, dice, complete;
  function moveIt(){
    dice = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1,
    currDice = 40,
    complete = dice * currDice,
    totDice = totDice+complete

    return totDice;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the browser's integrated console.

In Chrome: Tools > Javascript Console. Or CTRL + SHIFT + J. There you can console.log from your code and watch it there, or you can use the Sources tab (at the top of the panel). Navigate to the file, click on it and you can put a breakpoint in the line you want by ckicking the line number.

In Firefox: Tools > development > Web console. Or CTRL + SHIFT + K. Yu can debug in a similar fashion like the aforementioned.

You can also use tools like Firebug. See https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Debugging